# Counting Partial Orders Using Sub-lattices (Stanley EC Chapter 3 Problem 46a)

Tags: combinatorics, lattice-orders

I was having difficulty with problem 46a in Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics chapter 3 (page 111):

Let $f(n)$ be the number of sublattices of rank $n$ of the Boolean Algebra $B_n$. Show that $f(n)$ is also the number of partial orders $P$ on $[n]$.

I am not exactly sure what a sublattice of rank $n$ would look like, particularly in this case. I also don't know what a partial order on $[n]$ would look like either.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try to write down a bijection between them, assigning to each partial order on $[n]$ a sublattice of the powerset of $[n]$ and vice versa. Looking at small values of $n$ may be helpful.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Could you show for a small example of n what a partial order on [n] would look like. I don't know what I'm trying to biject to.

Comment: Do you know what a partial order is? It's a set equipped with a relation satisfying some axioms. A partial order on $[n]$ is a relation on $[n]$ satisfying some axioms. For example, there is the total order $1 \le 2 \le 3 \le \dots \le n$.